# Where do I define the instance ID to start?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-ec2

I haven't found an answer for this yet, and I've tried putting the instance ID I want to turn off/on:

```
ec2 = aws.createEC2Client(yourAccessKeyId, yourSecretAccessKey);

ec2.call("StartInstances", {}, function(err, result) {
  console.log(result);
})
```

Where in that script do I need to define the instance I want to start?

Comment: Which AWS wrapper for Node are you using?  http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/EC2/Client.html clearly describes that .startInstances takes a `params` object that includes a `InstanceIds` string array specifying which instances to start.

Comment: Joe, that did it.  I was calling instanceIds, not InstanceIds...thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

As Joe pointed out in his comment, `startInstances` takes an object parameter `param` which has to have an `InstanceIds` property. See more in the [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/EC2_20130201.html#startInstances-property) for the AWS SDK for Node.js.